# Mapping DNS to Azure VM

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have a ASP.NET website hosted at a hosting provider (Windows Server 2012 IIS 8) which is down most of the time. I have my domain name registered through them which I do not intend moving as of now.

I am moving my hosting to Azure VM. Here's what I have already done.

- Created virtual machine in Azure with static IP.
- Created a DNS called red-seau-cloudapp-azure.
- Added endpoint on public port 80. So Website can be accessed via localhost and via http:// ipaddress/ (outside of VM)

On my existing hosting provider, I see the following DNS entries.

```
NS ns1.myhost.arvixevps.com    
NS ns2.myhost.arvixevps.com    
A < ipaddress >    
* A < ipaddress >    
www A < ipaddress >    
mail A < ipaddress >    
mail2 A < ipaddress >    
MX [10], mail.mywebsite.com    
MX [21], mail2.mywebsite.com    
TXT globalsign-domain-verification=SKFHKSJHDLKUERIJKDCFJLKF_234KJFDJK
```

**Q1.** What do I need change in these entries so that www.mywebsite.com points to the website hosted on Azure VM instead of my old hosting?

**Q2.** Is it possible that I keep my mail server on my old hosting and move only my website to point to Azure VM?

Comment: It looks as if this should probably be moved to Server Fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1. What do I need change in these entries so that www.mywebsite.com
>   points to the website hosted on Azure VM instead of my old hosting?

You would need to change the `A` record to point to the IP address of your new Virtual Machine in Azure. However for this, you would need to ensure that the IP address of your Virtual Machine does not change which would cost more. Another alternative is to use `CNAME` mapping where you map your domain to the DNS name of your Azure Virtual Machine. You may find this link helpful: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name-portal/ (see the instructions for Azure Portal and not Azure Classic Portal there).

> Q2. Is it possible that I keep my mail server on my old hosting and
>   move only my website to point to Azure VM?

Yes, it is entirely possible to do so. Only change the DNS records that you want (A, CNAME etc.) and leave the MX records unchanged.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. I have created virtual machine in Azure with static IP. Is there still a possibility that it will change. You also said that another alternative is to use CNAME mapping where you map your domain to the DNS name of your Azure Virtual Machine. In this case, will my CNAME mapping be red-seau-cloudapp-azure? What do I keep the 'A' records as if I am using CNAME mapping?

Comment: Based on this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/, if you use a reserved ip address, then it won't change. For the CNAME record, you're correct, it should be `www` maps to your VM's DNS address. Regarding your last question, I believe you would need `A` record mapping if you want to point your naked domain (i.e. with `www`) to your VM, though I am not 100% sure. HTH.

Comment: Is there a difference between reserved ip address and static id address? In the configuration, I can chose dynamic vs static IP. I chose static. Will it ever change?

Comment: Ok I got my answer to private vs reserved via this - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lalitesh_kumar/2014/10/06/static-ip-reserved-ip-and-instance-level-ip-in-azure/